# Can't close a Pop Up

Tags: javascript, css

I maked a pop-up with html and css, when I click on a button,
it's should close the pop-up with css :

```
function creditsPopUpClose(){
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("bodyid").style.opacity = 1;
    audio2.play();
}
```

But it don't close the pop-up but it open another pop-up.

```
function creditsPopUpOpen(){
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("bodyid").style.opacity = 0.5; 
    audio.play();
}

function creditsPopUpClose(){
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("bodyid").style.opacity = 1;
    audio2.play();
}

function pricesPopUpOpen(){
    document.getElementById("pricesPopUp").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("bodyid").style.opacity = 0.5; 
    audio.play();
}

function pricesPopUpClose(){
    document.getElementById("pricesPopUp").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("bodyid").style.opacity = 1;
    audio2.play();
}
```

(It's open the prices pop-up)

```
<div class="popUp" id="popUp">
    <p>Made by Nano-Geek </p>
    <p>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.zapsplat.com/sound-effect-category/button-clicks/">Sounds Effects</a> ●
        <a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Favicon</a>
        <a style="color: #fff;" onclick="creditsPopUpClose()">Close</a>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="popUp" id="pricesPopUp">
    <p class="priceText">
        Autoclicker : <p id="autoclickerPrice"></p> clicks.<br>
        Factory : <p id="factoryPrice"></p> clicks.
    </p>
    <a style="color: #fff;" onclick="pricesPopUpClose()">Close</a>
</div>
```

I don't see where is the problem, it is my browser ?

Comment: Nano, you are not showing any html here, we dont know what bodyId and pricesPopUp are, anyways, you shouldn't use a popUp with opacity 0, opacity will leave the element invisible but it will still be there using up space

Comment: Can you put your code in the snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: First thing you should try is to replace `style.opacity = 0;` with `style.display = "none";` and `style.opacity = 1;` with `style.display = "block".

Comment: Most likely, you are calling the wrong function on the button click.

Comment: @besciualex I tried to replace style.opacity = 0; with style.display = "none"; and style.opacity = 1; with `style.display = "block" but it's don't work, the pop-up open but is invisible, I added style.opacity = 1; after your code but it's don't change : I still can't close.

Comment: Because he uses opacity, at one moment there is an popup which has opacity set as zero, but overlaps his HIDE button, therefore it 'disables' its functionality. That's what happens.

Comment: @besciualex I added your code to the two pop-up and it's finnally work ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Consider [accepting the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented your `audio.play();` functions to prevent an Undefined error. 
When you work with popups you don't hide the body, nor use `opacity` property. Just show something on top of it (using `z-index` and `position: fixed` and `display: block` properties)

```js
function creditsPopUpOpen(){
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.display = 'block';
    //audio.play();
}

function creditsPopUpClose(){
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.display = 'none';
    //audio2.play();
}

function pricesPopUpOpen(){
    document.getElementById("pricesPopUp").style.display = 'block';
    //audio.play();
}

function pricesPopUpClose(){
    document.getElementById("pricesPopUp").style.display = 'none';
    //audio2.play();
}
```

```css
a{
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popUp{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.9)
}
```

```html
<div class="popUp" id="popUp">
    <p>Made by Nano-Geek </p>
    <div>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.zapsplat.com/sound-effect-category/button-clicks/">Sounds Effects</a> ●
        <a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Favicon</a>
        <a style="color: #ff0000;" onclick="creditsPopUpClose()">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="popUp" id="pricesPopUp">
    <div class="priceText">
        Autoclicker : <p id="autoclickerPrice"></p> clicks.<br>
        Factory : <p id="factoryPrice"></p> clicks.
    </div>
    <a style="color: #ff0000;" onclick="pricesPopUpClose()">Close</a>
</div>

<a onclick='creditsPopUpOpen()'>creditsPopUpOpen</a>
<br />
<br />
<a onclick='pricesPopUpOpen()'>pricesPopUpOpen</a>
```